# How to fix java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=1

Tags: android, indexoutofboundsexception

I am creating an android application that consists of a serial communication.I am getting an error **called java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=1** please tell me how to fix it

This is my usb driver:

```
public class UsbDriver {

    private final Context mApplicationContext;
    private final UsbManager mUsbManager;
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private final UsbConnectionHandler mConnectionHandler;
    private final int VID;
    private final int PID;
    protected static final String ACTION_USB_PERMISSION = "ch.serverbox.android.USB";
    public static int Device_Exception;
    public static UsbDevice Device_Details;
    public static UsbEndpoint Data_In_End_Point = null;
    public static UsbEndpoint Data_Out_End_Point = null;
    public static UsbDeviceConnection USB_Device_Connection;

    public UsbDriver(Activity parentActivity,UsbConnectionHandler connectionHandler, int vid, int pid) {
        mApplicationContext = parentActivity.getApplicationContext();
        mConnectionHandler = connectionHandler;
        mUsbManager = (UsbManager) mApplicationContext.getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);
        VID = 1027;
        PID = 24577;
        Device_Exception = 0;
    //  init();
        Check_Devices();
    }

    private void Check_Devices() {
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        int j=0;
        HashMap<String, UsbDevice> devlist = mUsbManager.getDeviceList();
        Iterator<UsbDevice> deviter = devlist.values().iterator();
        Device_Details = null;
        if (devlist.size() != 0) {              
            while (deviter.hasNext()) {
                Device_Details = deviter.next();
                if (Device_Details.getVendorId() == VID && Device_Details.getProductId() == PID){
                    if (!mUsbManager.hasPermission(Device_Details)){
                        onPermissionDenied(Device_Details);
                    } else {
                        UsbDeviceConnection conn = mUsbManager.openDevice(Device_Details);
                        if (!conn.claimInterface(Device_Details.getInterface(1), true)){
                            return;
                        }

                        conn.controlTransfer(0x21, 34, 0, 0, null, 0, 0);
                        conn.controlTransfer(0x21, 32, 0, 0,new byte[] { (byte) 0x80, 0x25 , 0x00, 0x00,0x00, 0x00, 0x08 }, 7, 0);
                        USB_Device_Connection=conn; 
                        Data_In_End_Point = null;
                        Data_Out_End_Point = null;

                        UsbInterface usbIf = Device_Details.getInterface(1);
                        for (int i = 0; i < usbIf.getEndpointCount(); i++) {
                            if (usbIf.getEndpoint(i).getType() == UsbConstants.USB_ENDPOINT_XFER_BULK) {
                                if (usbIf.getEndpoint(i).getDirection() == UsbConstants.USB_DIR_IN)
                                    Data_In_End_Point = usbIf.getEndpoint(i);
                                else
                                    Data_Out_End_Point = usbIf.getEndpoint(i);
                            }
                        }
                        if (Data_In_End_Point == null || Data_Out_End_Point == null)
                            Device_Exception = 2;
                    }
                    break;
                }j++;
            }
            if (Device_Details == null) {
                Device_Exception = 3;
                return;
            }
        }
        else {
            Device_Exception = 1;
            return;
        }
    }

    public void onPermissionDenied(UsbDevice d) {
        UsbManager usbman = (UsbManager) mApplicationContext.getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mApplicationContext, 0, new Intent(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION), 0);
        mApplicationContext.registerReceiver(mPermissionReceiver,new IntentFilter(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION));
        usbman.requestPermission(d, pi);
    }

    private class PermissionReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        private final IPermissionListener mPermissionListener;

        public PermissionReceiver(IPermissionListener permissionListener){
            mPermissionListener = permissionListener;
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            mApplicationContext.unregisterReceiver(this);
            if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION)) {
                if (!intent.getBooleanExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_PERMISSION_GRANTED, false)) {
                    mPermissionListener.onPermissionDenied((UsbDevice) intent.getParcelableExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_DEVICE));
                } else {
                    l("Permission granted");
                    UsbDevice dev = (UsbDevice) intent.getParcelableExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                    if (dev != null){
                        if (dev.getVendorId() == VID && dev.getProductId() == PID) {
                            Check_Devices() ;
                        }
                    }else{
                        e("device not present!");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private BroadcastReceiver mPermissionReceiver = new PermissionReceiver(new IPermissionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPermissionDenied(UsbDevice d) {
            l("Permission denied on " + d.getDeviceId());
        }
    });

    private static interface IPermissionListener {
        void onPermissionDenied(UsbDevice d);
    }

    public final static String TAG = "USBController";

    private void l(Object msg) {
        Log.d(TAG, ">==<" + msg.toString() + " >==<");
    }

    private void e(Object msg) {
        Log.e(TAG, ">==< " + msg.toString() + " >==<");
    }
}
```

This is my usb connection handler

```
public interface UsbConnectionHandler {
    void onUsbStopped();
    void onErrorLooperRunningAlready();
    void onDeviceNotFound();
}
```

This is my main activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    EditText communication_data;
    Button send;

    public static final int targetVendorID = 1027;      
    public static final int targetProductID = 24577;
    public  UsbManager manager;
    public  UsbDeviceConnection usbDeviceConnection;
    public  UsbInterface usbInterfaceFound = null;
    public  UsbEndpoint endpointOut = null;
    public  UsbEndpoint endpointIn = null;
    public  UsbDevice usbdevice,device_details;
    public  UsbEndpoint listusbendpoint;
    private static final int VID = 1027;
    private static final int PID = 24577;
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private static UsbDriver Usb_Driver_class;
    ActionBar actionbar;
    UsbConnectionHandler connectionHandler;
    public static UsbDriver USB_Driver_Child;
    public static boolean Communication_Failed,Frame_Ok,Total_Frame_Decoded;
    static byte[] Communication_Byte;
    HashMap<String, UsbDevice> devicelist= null;
    static byte[] sample;
    static boolean Communication_Ok;
    static int Sequence_No,Response_Time;
    Thread Receive;
    ByteBuffer buffer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //communication_data = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText_comm);
        send = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1_sendin);

        send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Communication_Byte=new byte[1];
                if(Check_Devices_Available()==true) {   
                    int Packet_Size = USB_Driver_Child.Data_In_End_Point.getMaxPacketSize();
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,""+Packet_Size, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Receive.start();
                    Communication_Ok=false;
                    for(int i=0;(i<5 && Communication_Ok!=true);i++)    
                    Send_Communication_Check_Command();

                    if(Communication_Ok)
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Communication Successfully Established", 1000).show();
                    else
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Communication Failure", 10000).show();
                }                   
            }

            private boolean Check_Devices_Available() {
                Usb_Driver_class = new UsbDriver(MainActivity.this, connectionHandler, VID, PID);

                if(USB_Driver_Child.Device_Exception==0){
                    if(USB_Driver_Child.USB_Device_Connection==null || USB_Driver_Child.Data_Out_End_Point==null)
                        return false;   

                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Device Found", 1000).show();  
                    return true;
                }else if(USB_Driver_Child.Device_Exception==1){
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"No Devices Attached ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
                    return false;
                }else if(USB_Driver_Child.Device_Exception==2){
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Device Found,But No End Points", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();   
                    return false;
                }else if(USB_Driver_Child.Device_Exception==3){
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Unable to Open Device", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();    
                    return false;
                }
                return false;
            }

            Thread Receive  = new Thread(new Runnable(){

                @SuppressWarnings("unused")
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Sequence_No=0;
                    buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(64);
                    sample = new byte[64];
                    int Frame_Size;
                    UsbRequest request = new UsbRequest();
                    int i,j;
                    byte [] datarx=new byte[1]; 
                    char q;
                    while (true) {
                        request.initialize(UsbDriver.USB_Device_Connection, UsbDriver.Data_In_End_Point);
                        request.queue(buffer, 64);
                        if (UsbDriver.USB_Device_Connection.requestWait() == request) {
                            sample=buffer.array(); 
                            for(i=0;i<64;i++){
                                if(sample[i]=='&'){
                                    Communication_Ok=true;
                                    break;
                                }else if(sample[i]==0x03){
                                    if(sample[0]==0x02)
                                    //Frame_Ok=true;    
                                    break;
                                }                               
                            }

                            if(Frame_Ok==true){
                                //Frame_Ok=false;
                                //if(sample[1]==1)
                                //Coil_No=1;
                                //else
                                //Coil_No=2;
                                //Response_Time= (int)(((sample[2]&0x00FF)<<8) + (sample[3]&0x00FF));

                                //Total_Frame_Decoded=true;
                                //sample = null;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

            private void Send_Communication_Check_Command() {
                long i,j;
                Communication_Byte[0]='&';
                UsbDriver.USB_Device_Connection.bulkTransfer(UsbDriver.Data_Out_End_Point,Communication_Byte, 1, 0);
                for(i=0;(i<1000 && Communication_Ok!=true) ;i++)    
                    for(j=0;(j<1000 && Communication_Ok!=true);j++);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

This is my logcat:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(2452): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(2452): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=1
E/AndroidRuntime(2452):     at android.hardware.usb.UsbDevice.getInterface(UsbDevice.java:155)
E/AndroidRuntime(2452):     at com.developer.milancomm.UsbDriver.Check_Devices(UsbDriver.java:74)
E/AndroidRuntime(2452):     at com.developer.milancomm.UsbDriver.<init>(UsbDriver.java:48)
E/AndroidRuntime(2452):     at com.developer.milancomm.MainActivity$1.Check_Devices_Available(MainActivity.java:86)
E/AndroidRuntime(2452):     at com.developer.milancomm.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:63)
E/AndroidRuntime(2452):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240)
E/AndroidRuntime(2452):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721)
E/AndroidRuntime(2452):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
E/AndroidRuntime(2452):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
E/AndroidRuntime(2452):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
E/AndroidRuntime(2452):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
E/AndroidRuntime(2452):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(2452):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
E/AndroidRuntime(2452):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
E/AndroidRuntime(2452):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
E/AndroidRuntime(2452):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: post logcat in which line it is getting

Comment: I posted my logcat dude check it @NoName

Comment: `Device_Details.getInterface(1)` is the problem. It looks like the underlaying data structure contains only one element,

Answer (score 14, accepted):

An Array length of 1 means that only the index 0 exist, because in java array indexes start with 0!

Or in other words the Boundaries of an Array are Array.length -1

Comment: What is reason behide Array.get(-1) isn't working directly .... -1 means last index ... in that sense??

Answer (score 5):

**length = 1** means that the array has only 1 element in it, and java is zero based numbering (which means that indexing an array starts from 0 not 1).

since you have only one element in the array, this means that you need to access it with **index = 0** , not **index = 1**

this is what the error trying to tell you.

Answer (score 1):

The Logcat indicates you are having error at line 74 in UsbDriver Class at:

`if (!conn.claimInterface(Device_Details.getInterface(1), true))  { ...}`

try replacing with 0 in the place of 1.

I don't know why you hardcoded this with 1.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you set a size/length for the array